# Text-align center doesn't center items in navbar

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a problem that I can't center items inside my navbar. They are still appears on a left side. I'm using React

My Navbar code

```
<div className="header">
              <div className="navbar">
                <Navbar fixed="top" bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Darzi Apartments</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="#new-homes">New Homes</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#commercial-premises">Commercial Premises</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="construction-services">Construction Services</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#careers">Careers</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#about-us">About us</Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
            </div>
            </div>
```

CSS part

```
.header {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

What I should specify in CSS to make items in Navbar be in center of Navbar?

Comment: if by items you mean the navigation links just change the mr-auto className in the Nav to mx-auto and that should center the nav

Comment: @FKIng Thanks ! It works for me! But if I want to center this part as well? `  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Darzi Apartments</Navbar.Brand>`

Comment: @FKIng Cause it stays on the left side, but every other one in the middle now.

Comment: In that case try adding these classes to the Navbar d-flex, justify-content-between, align-items-center. That should display the contents of the navbar in flexbox and also center them both vertically and horizontally

Answer (score 0):

The 'text-align' attribute aligns the text INSIDE the element, not the 'text-element'.
You can read more about text-alignment here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP

There are several ways to align the html-elements in the center of your navigation bar, my preferred choice is using 'flexbox'.

Here are some resources regarding flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to your `.js` file not being a `.jsx` file and therefore `className` isn't valid. By changing `className` to `class` it worked for me. So i'd try changing the extension if I were you.

Answer (score -2):

To align everything in the header class at the center.

```
.header {
   display:flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

These styles should work for any element you want to center their children.